# XCTest.framework/XCTest: no matching architecture in universal wrapper when run the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can anyone explain to me what is going are here?
I don't understand what this error means.

> XCTest.framework/XCTest: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

I got error when i add this framework and run my app

> Nimble.framework
>
> Quick.framework

[image]

[image: image2]

Comment: Add you code. not just the error. you need to tell where you are getting this error.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier when i run my app , and i add another image

Comment: Im not the person who can help you solve this. but i can tell you that if you want to get help on this site. you need to put the code where you are getting error and not just the image of the result.

Comment: and from what I see I think you have not set the path to your images correctl. I could be wrong.

Comment: bro i don't get error in the code , i got like the error in image not in my code , when i run my app i got this error like in image

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to embed `XCTest.framework` into main project target. Usually this error means you're trying to use framework which was compiled to other architectures. For example running on physical device `XCTest` which was compiled for simulator only.